# How to get woocommerce attributes used for product variations?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I'm trying to get a list with all woocommerce attributes and values, but only those used for product variations (for example, I want to get "size" and "color" values, but not other attributes  used only for information purposes like "fabric" or "weight").

I'm using this code:

```
$allAttributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
foreach ($allAttributes as $att) {
  $wcAttribute = wc_get_attribute($att->attribute_id);
  [...]
}
```

At this point, I want to check if this $wcAttribute is used for any product variation, to add it to my list or not, but I don't know how to proceed.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I respond to myself, because I found a solution. Probably, it isn't the best solution, but it works (if someone has any better solution, I'll appreciate):

```
  function getAllWCAttributes()
  {
    /* Format for attributes: ['attribute_id' => ['id', 'name', 'values'=>['id', 'name'] ] ]*/
    $attributes = array();
    $allAttributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
    foreach ($allAttributes as $att) {
      if (isAttributeUsedForVariations($att)) {
        $wcAttTerms = get_terms('pa_' . $att->attribute_name);
        $terms = array();
        foreach ($wcAttTerms as $wcTerm) {
          $terms[] = array(
            'id' => $wcTerm->term_id,
            'name' => $wcTerm->name
          );
        }
        $attributes[$att->attribute_id] = array(
          'id' => $att->attribute_id,
          'name' => $att->attribute_label,
          'values' => $terms
        );
      }
    }
    return $attributes;
  }
  
  function isAttributeUsedForVariations($attribute)
  {
    $terms = array();
    $attTerms =  get_terms('pa_' . $attribute->attribute_name);
    foreach ($attTerms as $attTerm) {
      $terms[] = $attTerm->slug;
    }
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product_variation',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'attribute_pa_' . $attribute->attribute_name,
          'value' => $terms,
          'compare'  =>  'IN'
        )
      )
    );
    $variationsQuery = new WP_Query($args);
    return ($variationsQuery->post_count > 0)? true: false;
  }
```

Documentation:

[wc_get_attribute_taxonomies()](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_get_attribute_taxonomies)

[get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

[WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)